# WiFi network disappeared?

Tags: wifi, ssh, pi-4, access-point, hostapd

I set up my RasPi 4 as a WiFi Access Point according to [this guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md), and it worked - I could see the SSID in the list of networks, and join the WiFi network, and connect using `ssh`, but only for a brief, 10-minute period.

My `ssh` connection froze and I had to terminate the session and now the SSID is not showing up in my list of networks on any of my devices.

Not quite sure how to begin to debug this.

Comment: `sudo systemctl status` for both `hostapd` and `dnsmasq` shows that they are `active (running)`, although I just noticed that  `warning: interface wlan0 does not currently exist` returns from `sudo systemctl status dnsmasq`.  I will investigate further

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the RPI?

Answer (score -1):

ok - so the trick was to unhash `allow-hotplug wlan0` in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

solution came from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=164134).

Comment: hmmm ok - nope.  this is **not** the solution - SSID disappeared again.  still looking for a solution

Answer (score -1):

I think the real culprit was that the inbuilt WiFi adaptor was too weak.  I've set it up to use a USB WiFi dongle, and it seems to be working well now.

Comment: Please don't create always a new answer. Instead edit your first answer and modify it. There is a link below the answer, named [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/106192/edit). And please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again months for months.